# Propositional variables in semantic equivalence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm learning the semantic equivalence rules/laws in propositional logic, but I'm confused by what the propositional variables in the rules are supposed to represent.

For example, the associative rules are listed as

$A ∧ ( B ∧ C) ≡ (A ∧ B) ∧ C$

$A ∨ ( B ∨ C) ≡ (A ∨ B) ∨ C$

and I have read that the following is valid

$p ∨ (p ∨ ¬p)$

$≡ (associativity)$

$(p ∨ p) ∨ ¬p$

but I do not understand why.

If $C$ represents $¬p$, then that means both $A$ and $B$ represent the same proposition ($p$). If this is possible, then why does the rule specify three distinct propositions ($A$, $B$, and $C$)?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: They're just variables, ranging over formulas. If distinct real variables $x,y$ can sometimes represent the same number, why can't $A$ and $B$? Of course it's possible. The case where $A=B$ arises when the same formula is substituted for both $A$ and $B$. Why are three variables used? Well, c'mon: you know the associative law for numbers, right? $a(b+c) = ab + ac$. Why are three variables used there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $C$ represents $¬p$, then that means both $A$ and $B$ represent the same proposition ($p$).   If this is possible, then why does the rule specify three distinct propositions ($A$, $B$, and $C$)?

The tokens $A, B, C$ *may* represent distinct propositions, but they are not *required* to be so.   The rule applies to any three propositions, whether or not they are distinct.

Three different tokens are used so that you know *where* to place substitutions.   When you replace $A$ by something (say $p$) you replace *all* instances of $A$ with it.   When you replace $B$ by something (which may *or* may not be the same thing) all instances of $B$ are replaced by that.   And so forth.

The rule $(A\vee B)\vee C = A\vee (B\vee C)$, implies that $(P\vee P)\vee Q= P\vee (P\vee Q) \\ (X\vee Y)\vee X = X\vee (Y\vee X)\\ (Z\vee Z)\vee Z = Z\vee (Z\vee Z) \\ \textsf{et cetera}$.

Take the rule, and substitute $p$ for $A$ to obtain: $(p\vee B)\vee C = p \vee (B\vee C)$, then substitute $p$ for $B$ to obtain, $(p\vee p)\vee C = p\vee (p\vee C)$ and finally substituting $\neg p$ for $C$ obtains $(p\vee p)\vee\neg p = p\vee(p\vee\neg p)$ .

---

Likewise using the rule $(A\vee B)\wedge C = (A\wedge C)\vee (B\wedge C)$ and *the same substitution* obtains $(p\vee p)\wedge \neg p = (p\wedge\neg p)\vee (p\wedge\neg p)$ but does **not** *ever* result in $(p\vee p)\wedge \neg p = (p\wedge p)\vee (\neg p\wedge p)$.